# Pass event to function?

Tags: jquery

How can I pass the event from a mouseup event to a function?

my code so far

```
$(".add, .remove").on("mouseup", getCart);

function getCart(e)
{
    post_data = {"id" : e.attr('data-productNumber'), "action" : e.attr('data-action')}
}
```

I'm getting a `TypeError: Cannot read property 'attr' of undefined`. So I'm guessing the event is not getting passed.

Comment: here you are not passing any parameter to the function. That's why it's throwing a error

Comment: You must register the function, not its call:  `getCart` instead of `getCart()`

Comment: @DenysSéguret I removed the parenteses and get a "e.attr is not a function" now

Comment: @Canvas - not sure it helps to edit the question. Write it as an answer otherwise people who read this in the future will wonder what the fuss was about.

Comment: Yes, events don't have a attr function. What are you trying to do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The event object does not have and `attr` method. You probably need `e.target` to reference the element that got the event. A jQuery element will have the `attr` method.

So:

```
$(e.target).attr('data-productNumber')
```

...etc.

If the targeted element is the same as the element on which you have the selector, i.e. with the *add* or *remove* class, you can also use `this`:

```
$(this).attr('data-productNumber')
```

NB: jQuery [loads the `data-` attributes](https://api.jquery.com/data/#data-html5) in its data object, so you can do the above also like this:

```
$(e.target).data('productNumber')
$(this).data('productNumber')
```

Comment: How do you know it's about the target ? It could as well be just `this`, or anything

Answer (score -2):

pass the target element to the function.

```
$(".add, .remove").on("mouseup", getCart($(".add, .remove")));

function getCart(e)
{
  post_data = {"id" : e.attr('data-productNumber'), "action" : e.attr('data-action')}
 }
```

Comment: The problem is that it triggers before you even click. That is because the function is called (note the parentheses), instead of being passed on as event handler.

Comment: did you checked @vandelay code? I just added solution the way he written.

Comment: did you notice the update in the question made 16 minutes ago, after comments were made about this very issue?

Comment: I understood the function running before the events occurs. But it's giving the attr val. That's what I trying to say here.